# Logging - Log4j2 logging issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am currently working on an application that is using Log4j2 for logging.

Below is the Log4j2.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" packages="myappsystem">
<Appenders>
    <MyDockerAppender name="STDOUT" />
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="myappsystem"  level="INFO"/>
    <Root level="ERROR" additivity="true" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Now the challenge that I am facing here is the logger seems to be logging only when I do something like below

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("myappsystem");
LOGGER.info("Entering method");
```

The problem here is, It is not giving me the details of the class files from which this particular line is being logged.

So, I tried to do something like below:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyServiceImpl.class);
```

This doesn't seem to be working.
Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logger is configured for

```
<logger name="myappsystem"  level="INFO"/>
```

and therefore

`LogManager.getLogger("myappsystem");`

works.

If you use

```
LogManager.getLogger(MyServiceImpl.class);
```

you have to configure a Logger starting with the fully qualified Classname (with packages) like you use in `<logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>`

So i.e.

```
<logger name="my.project.package.structure"  level="INFO"/>
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks! But the problem that I see here is, I have a large number of classes under several packages. It doesn't make sense to mention each and every package. Anyways that you could suggest to make this generic?

Comment: You can use a higher level package name. So <logger name="my.project" level="INFO" /> Similar to "org.springframework" which logs out for all classes in that package structure.

Comment: Tried something like this.  <logger name="com.myproject.mysystem.myarchive" level="INFO" />. Worked like a charm! Thanks guys!